# issues looping through descendant

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm fairly new to using linq and I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I have searched the internet and found several examples but none of them are returning the results I need. I am able to loop through the machine names. Now I want to loop through that to grab the features for that server. Below is an example of my XML followed by the code I'm using. Instead of returning two features, it's returning six of them (for all servers). I'm sure there's a better way of doing this but I have tried many variations.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Enterprise xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Version>4.2</Version>
  <Sites>
    <Site>
      <Machines>
        <Machine>
          <MachineName>1950-16-CORE</MachineName>
          <ServerRole>CoreServer</ServerRole>
          <ClientRoles>Core</ClientRoles>
          <Features>
            <Feature>
              <FeatureName>CoreProcess</FeatureName>
              <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
            </Feature>
            <Feature>
              <FeatureName>Antivirus</FeatureName>
              <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
            </Feature>
          </Features>
        </Machine>
        <Machine>
          <MachineName>1950-16-COREX</MachineName>
          <ServerRole>CoreExpansionServer</ServerRole>
          <ClientRoles>CoreEx</ClientRoles>
          <Features>
            <Feature>
              <FeatureName>CoreExProcess</FeatureName>
              <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
            </Feature>
            <Feature>
              <FeatureName>Antivirus</FeatureName>
              <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
            </Feature>
          </Features>
        </Machine>
        <Machine>
          <MachineName>1950-16-PRIDB</MachineName>
          <ServerRole>DatabaseServer</ServerRole>
          <ClientRoles>NONE</ClientRoles>
          <Features>
            <Feature>
              <FeatureName>MSSQL</FeatureName>
              <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
            </Feature>
            <Feature>
              <FeatureName>Antivirus</FeatureName>
              <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
            </Feature>
          </Features>
        </Machine>
      </Machines>
    </Site>
  </Sites>
  <GeneratedOn>2013-02-15T18:11:45.0345530Z</GeneratedOn>
</Enterprise>
```

Code:

```
    private void ParseXMLData()
    {
        if (File.Exists(xmlFile))
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@xmlFile);
            IEnumerable<XElement> siteRows = from siterow in xmlDoc.Descendants("Sites")
                                         select siterow;

            foreach (XElement xEleSite in siteRows)
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> siteLists = from siteList in xEleSite.Descendants("Site")
                                                  select siteList;

                var machines = from ms in siteLists.Descendants("Machine")
                               select new
                               {
                                   machineName = ms.Element("MachineName").Value,
                                   serverRole = ms.Element("ServerRole").Value,
                                   clientRole = ms.Element("ClientRoles").Value,
                               };

                foreach (var server in machines)                    
                {
                    IEnumerable<XElement> machineRows = from machineRow in siteLists.Descendants("Machines")
                                                        select machineRow;

                    foreach (var currentServer in machineRows)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(server.machineName + "\r\n" + server.serverRole + "\r\n" + server.clientRole);

                        IEnumerable<XElement> featureLists = from features in currentServer.Descendants("Features")
                                                             select features;

                        var feature = from fs in featureLists.Descendants("Feature")
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          featureName = fs.Element("FeatureName").Value,
                                          featureEnabled = fs.Element("FeatureEnabled").Value,
                                      };

                        ArrayList alMachineFeature = new ArrayList();
                        ArrayList alMachineFeatureStatus = new ArrayList();

                        foreach (var fs in feature)
                        {
                            alMachineFeature.Add(fs.featureName.ToString());

                            if (fs.featureEnabled.ToString() == "true")
                            {
                                alMachineFeatureStatus.Add("YES");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alMachineFeatureStatus.Add("no");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XElement.Descendants("ElementName") is a recursive method: it'll return all of the node's descendants named "ElementName", regardless of how deep those descendants are.

If you want to go one level down at a time, use XElement.Elements("ElementName") for an enumerable list of immediate descendants of the current element.

```
var machines = xmlDoc.Descendants("Machine");

foreach(var machine in machines)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Machine: {0}", machine.Element("MachineName"));

    foreach(var feature in machine.Descendants("Feature").Select(f => new { 
              name= f.Element("FeatureName").Value, 
              enabled = f.Element("FeatureEnabled").Value 
            }))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  Feature: Name={0}, Enabled={1}", feature.name, feature.enabled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Elements() instead of Descendants() to get only the child elements of an XElement.